# how to count foreground segmented faces in image?

Tags: matlab, image-processing, computer-vision, matlab-cvst

i have applied foreground segmentation on an image.its now showing the white areas instead of those faces in original image.now i want to counnt those faces how to do it?? output image is attached.......................................................

```
close all;
clear all;
clc;
rgbInputImage = imread('Crowd-of-people-008.jpg');
labInputImage = applycform(rgbInputImage,makecform('srgb2lab'));
Lbpdfhe = fcnBPDFHE(labInputImage(:,:,1));
labOutputImage = cat(3,Lbpdfhe,labInputImage(:,:,2),labInputImage(:,:,3));
rgbOutputImage = applycform(labOutputImage,makecform('lab2srgb'));
figure, imshow(rgbInputImage);
figure, imshow(rgbOutputImage);
img=rgbOutputImage;
final_image = zeros(size(img,1), size(img,2));
if(size(img, 3) > 1)
for i = 1:size(img,1)
for j = 1:size(img,2)
R = img(i,j,1);
G = img(i,j,2);
B = img(i,j,3);
if(R > 92 && G > 40 && B > 20)
v = [R,G,B];
if((max(v) - min(v)) > 15)
if(abs(R-G) > 15 && R > G && R > B)
final_image(i,j) = 1;
end
end
end
end
end
end
binaryImage=im2bw(final_image,0.6);
figure, imshow(binaryImage);
binaryImage = imfill(binaryImage, 'holes');
figure, imshow(binaryImage);
%binaryImage = bwareaopen(binaryImage,1890); 
%figure,imshow(binaryImage);
%labeledImage = bwlabel(binaryImage, 8);
%blobMeasurements = regionprops(labeledImage, final_image, 'all');
%numberOfPeople = size(blobMeasurements, 1);
%imagesc(rgbInputImage); title('Outlines, from bwboundaries()');
%hold on;
%boundaries = bwboundaries(binaryImage);
%for k = 1 : numberOfPeople
%thisBoundary = boundaries{k};
%plot(thisBoundary(:,2), thisBoundary(:,1), 'g', 'LineWidth', 2);
%end
%imagesc(rgbInputImage);
%hold on;
%title('Original with bounding boxes');
%for k = 1 : numberOfPeople
%thisBlobsBox = blobMeasurements(k).BoundingBox;
%x1 = thisBlobsBox(1);
%y1 = thisBlobsBox(2);
%x2 = x1 + thisBlobsBox(3);
%y2 = y1 + thisBlobsBox(4);
%x = [x1 x2 x2 x1 x1];
%y = [y1 y1 y2 y2 y1];
%plot(x, y, 'LineWidth', 2);
%end  
binaryimage = bwboundaries(binaryimage);
imshow(binaryimage)
text(10,10,strcat('\color{green}Objects Found:',num2str(length(Binaryimage))))
hold on
for k = 1:length(Binaryimage)
boundary = Binaryimage{k};
plot(boundary(:,2), boundary(:,1), 'g', 'LineWidth', 0.2)
endB = bwboundaries(binaryimage);
imshow(binaryimage)
text(10,10,strcat('\color{green}Objects Found:',num2str(length(Binaryimage))))
hold on
end
for k = 1:length(B)
boundary = B{k};
plot(boundary(:,2), boundary(:,1), 'g', 'LineWidth', 0.2)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `[L, num] = bwlabel(BW, n)` to compute num, the number of connected components. See [here](http://de.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/bwlabel.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `vision.CascadeObjectDetector` in the Computer Vision System Toolbox to detect faces without background subtraction.